# removing x and y guides from a horizontal bar in pygal

Tags: python, pygal

am tryin to use show*_y_guides = False and it wont work. How do i make those dotted lines disappear.*

```
type hereimport pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, RotateStyle as RS
# Make the visualisation.
my_style = RS('#333366', base_style=LCS)

my_config = pygal.Config()
my_config.x_label_rotation = 45
my_config.legend_at_bottom = True
my_config.title_font_size = 24
my_config.label_font_size = 14
my_config.major_label_font_size = 18
my_config.truncate_label = 15
my_config.show_y_guides = False
my_config.width = 1000

line_chart = pygal.HorizontalBar(my_config, style=my_style)
line_chart.title = 'Browser usage evolution (in %)'

line_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013))
line_chart.add('Firefox', [None, None, 0, 16.6, 25, 31, 36.4, 45.5, 46.3, 42.8, 37.1])
line_chart.add('Chrome', [None, None, None, None, None, None, 0, 3.9, 10.8, 23.8, 35.3])
line_chart.add('IE', [85.8, 84.6, 84.7, 74.5, 66, 58.6, 54.7, 44.8, 36.2, 26.6, 20.1])
line_chart.add('Others', [14.2, 15.4, 15.3, 8.9, 9, 10.4, 8.9, 5.8, 6.7, 6.8, 7.5])
line_chart.render_to_file('hbar.svg')
```

this is my code

run the code to see the graph

Comment: why don't you post the graph so we can see it without having to install those libraries and run the code?